# Google cloud function (based on Java) needs only 24mb but Google's dashboard claims it uses 128mb+

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions

I created a simple Cloud Function that does nothing except receiving a PubSub event and printing out for much memory is used/free/etc (Runtime.getRuntime.*)

According to my logs, the JVM has allocated 24mb and can allocate at most 64mb. According to the google cloud dashboards, the function hovers around 120mb. It sometimes gets restarted because it supposedly uses >128mb (which is the limit I set)

How can i find out what the additional 100mb are required for?

Comment: Cloud function's memory usage might not be just the application code alone, it will have an execution context container more like a VM which also needs memory probably. Also when you use Runtime, you are issuing requests to that system, which probably needs memory and cpu to do that as well.

Comment: JVM memory footprint. The Achille heel of Java.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere definitely not the problem here, the discrepancy is huge and the OOM does not happen inside the JVM. it's always google that detects it.

-> Kris: this would mean that the 128mb setting is not even enough to run a "noop" function reliably. i can't see a justification for 128mb+ usage if all i do is "println("n bytes just arrived")

Comment: Can you check with the logs and metrics in cloud monitoring to find the details of what caused the issue. If you are not aware, you can check with this [link](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/1833?parent=catalog) on how to configure Viewing Cloud Function logs & metrics in Cloud Monitoring. Also check with this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848893).

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar in my case the cause were temp files, but the default dashboards don't show that